# A tool for monitoring progress and ETA of an arbitrary process

Tags: command-line, software-rec, watch, progress-information

I'm looking for a tool that takes two arguments:

- a command to execute, and
- a target value

The tool should then run the command continuously, look for a number in the output of the command, and estimate the time it will take until the number reaches the target value.

(I already know about [`pv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) and [`progress`](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress), but these are limited to data going through a pipe and coreutil tools respectively. I'm looking for something more generic.)

**Example:** Suppose I want to track of an `scp` file transfer. I would then check the size on the sending end, and continuously run `du -b` on the receiving end. It would look something like this:

```
$ du -bs source_directory
5798324564
$ *sometool* 5798324564 "ssh someserver du -bs destination_directory"
2019-01-28 21:03:10 - 23.2% - ETA 22:15:10 (1h 12m)
2019-01-28 21:03:40 - 26.3% - ETA 22:14:57 (1h 11m)
2019-01-28 21:04:10 - 29.3% - ETA 22:14:49 (1h 10m)
...
<continous output until 100% is reached>
...
2019-01-28 22:15:05 - 100% - done.
$
```

It would be similar to `watch` in the sense that it executes a given command repeatedly, but the difference being that instead of *printing* the output of the command, it should *look for a progress value* in the output, and compute an ETA.

Comment: I [asked this question before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/497284/109438) but I worded it poorly. It was hard to understand and it got closed and deleted. Here's another attempt. I also rolled up my sleeves and wrote a tool myself, which I shared in an answer below. Happy to hear about alternative tools as well. Perhaps there's an existing tool that I've missed.

Answer (score 4):

There's a tool that does precisely this. It's called `eta`.

Here's an example:

[image: eta example usage]

Here are some resources:

- [eta GitHub repo](https://github.com/aioobe/eta) (more usage examples in the README.md)
- [eta man page](https://github.com/aioobe/eta/wiki/eta-man-page)

Comment: Please explain the *advantage* of this tool compared to for example `pv`.

Comment: @sudodus The advantage of this tool compared to `pv` and `progress` is that it's not limited to stuff that goes through a pipe or to core util processes. As long as you have a way to estimate how far a process has come (`du  -bs`, `ls | wc -l`, `tail -f progress.log`, ...) this tool can display progress and eta.